# RecyclerView won't fill remaining space (ConstraintLayout)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make my RecyclerView fill the gap between two views, one at the top of the layout and the other at the bottom respectively. I've tried setting the RecyclerView's height to 0dp and setting the constraints down below but for some reason the RecyclerView isn't rendered at all. The adapter does in fact contain data and if I set the RecyclerView's height to an arbitrary value, say, 200dp then its rows show up as one would expect.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label_realm_filter"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_realm_filter_apply"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

Here's the rest of my layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded_edges"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_realm_filter"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/realm"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_realm_filter_close"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_realm_filter_close"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_realm_filter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/label_realm_filter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_realm_filter_apply"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_realm_filter_apply"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/apply"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What if you set `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"` to the `RecyclerView` .. I believe it's not necessary, but just in case... Also add a background color to the `RecyclerView` for testing purpose to make sure that the problem isn't from the row item layout

Comment: @Zain Tried it, the background color is only visible when I set the RecyclerView's height to a fixed size.

Comment: Your layout looks good. Use the "Layout Inspector" in Android Studio to see what is actually being rendered on screen. It may give you a clue to what's going on.

Comment: Maybe change the width of btn_realm_filter_apply to match_parent?